# Why would I use the web SDK versus a backend SDK with Firestore?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

By reading the Firestore documentation, I realised you could directly communicate with Firestore from a web app (for example).

Does that mean I could skip the backend for simple read/write operations, and use a backend in the middle when computation is required?

I currently have a Go backend on top of MySQL. I want to switch to NoSQL to improve the overall architecture.

In my current backend, I have to validate some rules here and there. I guess having these rules in the web app could be a security issue as they could be changed in a malicious way.

But in other cases, my backend is just playing the man in the middle: listen api request, retrieve data, respond.

These routes are good candidates to be replaced by a direct call to Firestore. But for the rest, I suppose I still have to stick to a backend to handle specific cases.

Is it okay to have such an hybrid approach?

Any use cases to clarify my idea on the topic?

Thank you!

Comment: Firebase has security rules for most purposes. If you want to modify data you are inserting - cloud function triggers might be of use. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/overview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite common to have a hybrid approach such as you describe, and there's nothing against it.

What matters is that:

- You ensure your clients can only access the data that they're authorized for using Firebase's server-side security rules.
- You ensure that client can only write data that is valid for your app, using  Firebase's server-side security rules.

You can then use server-side code, for example in Cloud Functions, to perform any operations that you find hard to capture securely in client-side code and security rules.

I often start by trying to have all my code in the clients, as it gives them the best offline experience. And I then only decide to move code to Cloud Functions if/when:

- The code needs to have access to secret values to perform its work, such as the API key for a payment processing gateway.
- The code itself is a secret, such as the cheat detection code for a game.
- The code needs more (CPU, disk, network) resources than many of my clients are likely to have, such as image resizing or, maybe more importantly, be on a constant power source.

Comment: Thank you for this clear answer :) "as it gives them the best offline experience": I'm exploring the capabilities or Firestore right now, and this is not primarly related to my initial question, but your statement seems to suggest that I could rely on Firestore to have some kind of cached data (or that I should not cache anymore). At the moment, I'm pulling data and holding it in localStorage to avoid too many calls. Should I rethink my way of working? Any links/docs that would help me to change my way of thinking. Clearly, switching to NoSQL looks promising but so new as well :)

Comment: I knew I should've elaborated on that part more. :)    Firestore indeed has a local cache on the device, which is uses for all read/write operations if the user is not connected to the backend. If you use a custom back-end, that won't automatically happen, although you can of course build your own offline storage as you've done.